# Image Segmentation

Tags: image, opencv, computer-vision, segment

So I am trying to write some code that lets me segment the fuses you see in the picture below. I have come up with two approaches:

1) Based on color. I threshold using OpenCV's inRange function. This approach works well for all fuses except the brown fuse. The brown fuse it too similar in colour with the fusebox itself and therefore it's very hard to segment it out.

2) I considered thresholding the image heavily so that I can detect the white points/terminals on the fuses themselves using OpenCV SimpleBlobDetector. I then filter out the blobs by their distances to each other. As I know the size of the fuses, I can filter out the invalid fuses. This approach works well for all fuses but the white one as it appears in even the most thresholded images.

I was hoping I could get a pointer on how to segment such an image. Would background subtraction work?

[image]

Comment: have you considered edge detection? you can use the detected edges to demarc the fuses and compare the colours.. since you already know the demarcation, it should be easy to find (all) the fuses.

Comment: Yes, I have. However, the edge between the brown fuse and the black fusebox is too soft and don't always appear as a complete contour around the fusebox.

Comment: Perhaps you could recognize the brown fuse by an absence of black.

Comment: This is the 3rd or 4th same question you posted :S

Comment: I don't think so. My other questions were about the same subject but were focused on different areas (for instance, one was about specifically matching the fuse colours). I do not have the luxury of discussing/asking-for-help from colleagues because I do not know anyone else who is into CV so SO is usually my first stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My experience with segmentation is that a single approach frequently does not work for difficult segmentation.  I if one algorithm works for all but brown and the other all but white, the union of the two should yield a complete result.  I know it is nice to have one elegant algorithm, but many of my best results have had to resort to the hybrid of multiple techniques.

I'd consider separating the channels into rgb and hue, saturation, and value and looking at each channel separately.  Sometimes browns that look very similar in color are have significantly different saturation or color channel values.  Adding and subtracting different channels can also sometimes enhance contrast.  This is simple but in many cases produces a fast and simple output that can be used for thresholding, watershed (see below), or perhaps background subtraction.

I think you might also want to try the [watershed algorithm](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html).  Many [examples](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/dbd/tutorial_distance_transform.html#gsc.tab=0) and [explainations](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/the-watershed-transform-strategies-for-image-segmentation.html) are [available](http://cmm.ensmp.fr/~beucher/wtshed.html).  Watershed requires that you provide a mask that contains the background (the fusebox and table) and a piece of each of the foreground objects (fuses).  As I understand it, you already can detect the contacts on the fuses so that piece is done.

Another approach is to just accept you can't see brown fuses.  If you can detect empty slots and every other color, you may be able to know by deduction where the brown ones are.

It's had to know what will work beforehand without some experimentation, but this should give you some ideas of how to improve what you have.

Comment: Thank you! I was under the impression that watershed is only for connected objects? Will it work for this case?

Comment: There is no need for the objects to be connected, although that is a use for watershed.  There are examples in [one of my links](http://cmm.ensmp.fr/~beucher/wtshed.html) for using it with unconnected objects and I've used to for unconnected objects as well.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

basic colour image segmentation code in C++ is available at  https://github.com/imensedave/basic_vision_region_segmentation

The trick with this approach is edge detection is done before colour regions are grown.